# Replace null values in a column corresponding to specific value in another column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['USA','USA','MEX','IND','UK','UK','UK'],
                   'Region': ['Americas','NaN','NaN','Asia','Europe','NaN','NaN'],
                   'Flower': ['Rose','Lily','Lily','Orchid','Petunia','Lotus','Dandelion']})
```

I want to replace the `NaN` values in Region with that of other regions. By which I mean if the country is USA or Mexico the region should be Americas and if the country is UK the region should be Europe.

The expected output is

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['USA','USA','MEX','IND','UK','UK','UK'],
                       'Region': ['Americas','Americas','Americas','Asia','Europe','Europe','Europe'],
                       'Flower': ['Rose','Lily','Lily','Orchid','Petunia','Lotus','Dandelion']})
```

I want to know an easy way to this without having to write if else statements.

Comment: Will it always be the case that countries in the same region will follow each other?  Or might you have `USA, IND, MEX, UK`?

Comment: `df['Region'] = df['Region'].ffill()`?

Comment: @ASGM they might not follow each other

Comment: make a dictionary, `d`, of the mappings then `df.fillna({'Region': df.Country.map(d)})`

Comment: As ALollz implies, you're going to need some other data (possibly in a dictionary where keys are countries and values are regions) with region-country matches before you can solve this problem.

Comment: Well if the data is complete enough, and uniquely paired, then the dictionary can be made from `d = df.dropna(subset=['Region']).set_index('Country').Region.to_dict()`

Comment: @ALollz yes thats correct i didn't think of this. I will make a dict and map it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code if ffill is not an option,

```
df['Region'] = np.select((df.Country.isin(['USA', 'MEX']), df.Country == 'UK'),
                         ('Americas', 'Europe'), df.Region)
```

Comment: yes i had to do this is my data wasn't uniquely paired